# Check connection details to SQL Server 2000/2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, monitoring, connections

I want to migrate some databases hosted in SQL Server 2000/2005 to SQL Server 2014.

I don't have direct access to the databases and I want to know all applications connecting to it and connection details. Is there any best way to get this information? I tried using DB profiling but its not allowed as its taking up lot of space on hosted DB server which causing disruptions.

Any better way like a SQL statement or remote connection monitoring will be helpful.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure regarding SQL Server 2000 since I did not work on it before, but if you want to check active transactions on SQL 2005, you can execute the following command `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`. to check active sessions execute `sp_who`.
Useful commands:

- check active queries

  ```
  SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
  req.session_id,
  req.status,
  req.command,
  req.cpu_time,
  req.total_elapsed_time
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
  ```

  **or**

  ```
  select
  P.spid
  ,   right(convert(varchar, 
          dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, P.last_batch, getdate()), '1900-01-01'), 
          121), 12) as 'batch_duration'
  ,   P.program_name
  ,   P.hostname
  ,   P.loginame
  from master.dbo.sysprocesses P
  where P.spid > 50
  and      P.status not in ('background', 'sleeping')
  and      P.cmd not in ('AWAITING COMMAND'
                  ,'MIRROR HANDLER'
                  ,'LAZY WRITER'
                  ,'CHECKPOINT SLEEP'
                  ,'RA MANAGER')
  order by batch_duration desc
  ```
- to check free disk space: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1706/determine-free-disk-space-in-sql-server-with-tsql-code/
- to check Server status I recommend to use activity monitor (you can use resource monitor as well).